# zoom in the GLPaint sample code

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

i would like to make an app where you can paint like in the GLPaint sample code, but also zoom in to paint in more detail within your painting.
but i get the feeling, that using OpenGL ES 1.0 which is used in the GLPaint app, is pretty difficult to learn and could be a little bit of an overkill for my need.
if i am chaning the main views frame with the setFrame method to zoom with gesturerecognizer, the already painted lines get erased with every change of the frames size.

so i tried to realize it with another idea: in the touchmoves method i add at "many" positions uiimageviews with an image of the brush, it is slower than the glpaint app and a little bit of a memomy management mess, but i don´t see another way to go there.

any suggestions, learn openGL ES 1.0 or 2.0 or trying to realise the last idea

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve what you are doing, however it will require some effort.

Usually zooming is quite straight-forward as most OpenGL scenes typically do not rely on the the accumulation buffer as the GLPaint sample code does.

If you try and just zoom your the view in GLPaint, your new painting will be drawn at some adjusted scale over your original drawing - which is almost certainly not what you want.

A work-around is instead of drawing directly to your presenting screen buffer, you would first render to a texture buffer, then render said texture buffer on a quad (or equivalent). That way the quad scene can be cleared and re-rendered every frame refresh (at any scale you choose) while your paint buffer retains its accumulation buffer.

This has been tested and works.

Answer (score -1):

I am quite sure the image view method will be an overkill after drawing for a few minutes... You can do all the zooming quite nicely with openGL and I suggest you do that. The bast practice would be to create a canvas as large as possible so when you zoom in you will not lose any resolution.

About zooming: Do not try to resize the GL frame or any frame for that matter because even if you manage to do that successfully you will lose resolution. You should use standard matrices to translate and scale the scene or just play around with `glOrtho` (set its values to the rect you are currently seeing). Once you get that part there are sadly 2 more things to do that require a bit of math, first is you will have to compute the new touch positions in the openGL scene as location in view will not know about your zooming and translating, second is you probably need to scale the brush as well (make smaller when the scene is bigger so you can draw details).

About the canvas: I do suggest you draw to a FBO rather then your main render buffer and present the texture to your main render scene. Note here that FBO will have attached texture and will be a size of power of 2 (create 2048x2048 or 4096x4096 for newer devices) but you will probably just be using some part of it to keep the same ratio as the screen (`glViewport` should do the job) so you will have to compute the texture coordinates. Overall the drawing mechanism doesn't change much.

So to sum this up, imagine you have a canvas (FBO) to which you apply the brush of certain size and position on touches events, then you use that canvas as a texture and draw it on your main GL view.

Comment: Down voted because you cannot simply zoom as you suggest because the GLPaint code depends on the accumulation buffer which is cleared each redraw.

Comment: I trust you are right about the GLPaint but I could hardly care less about how a simple sample project works. I am not suggesting modifying that sample project but rather create a new one which is designed to work for your needs. But if you do simply disable the clearing of the buffer on redraw or create an event buffer which can be used to redraw the scene after the clear. Anyway this is all out of the scope of this question which seems to be about an application LIKE GLPaint. So if you are interested in doing such a project you should know it usually takes a bit more then copying a sample.

Comment: I didn't ask this question, and I do not have an issue. I just found that your answer is incorrect and I don't want it to steer anyone in the wrong direction.

Comment: Also saying you don't care about GLPaint is the same as saying you don't actually care about answering the question, because that is what this question was about.

Comment: We might have a different view on the question then. Still I see your argument as invalid but as you said others might find it helpful. Since I see you do not agree with the answer I will be happy to up-vote your answer if a good solution will be introduced.

Comment: Great job. It would seem we both agree the best procedure would be drawing to a texture bound FBO. Your answer is pretty much the same as mine.

Comment: After reading your answer several more times, I do better understand your reply. I guess for me at least your answer was quite difficult to understand. I would change my down vote, but SO won't let me now

Comment: Don't worry about it. I am happy we resolved the answer.